# Play sounds in a loop from a list

Tags: python, audio, pygame

i got this list awith 2 sounds and i want to play them with this code.
Unfortunally it plays only the last sound of the list. I know that using pygame.Sound is a solution, but i don't know how to use it.

```
array = ["a.mp3", "b.mp3"] 
for i in range(len(array)):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(array[i])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: Your loop looks very java like. I'm not familiar with pygame but why not use `for sound in array:` then `.load(sound)` Just a suggestion. This doesn't answer your question although hope you get help!

Comment: Does this hae to use pygame? because winsound and snack could easily do this too

Comment: I think so, because i wanna use it for the Raspberry Pi later and i think WinSound and Snack does not support the Raspberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to play music with `pygame` **only** after creating a `display`, i.e.:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(pygame.display.list_modes()[-1]) # smallest resolution available
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('1.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.queue('2.mp3')

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

---

**Notes:**

- [pygame.mixer.music.queue](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue)

Comment: Wow, this is the solution, i just added that while condition into my code and it works!

Comment: That's great.GL